# Synchronization of multiple streams with Gstreamer

Tags: synchronization, gstreamer

I want to learn more about synchronization of different streams with RTCP with Gstreamer. A video was divided into 4 parts vertically so that synchronization can be better observed at the receiver. Following are the codes used for sender and receiver.

**sender:**

```
gst-launch -v \
\
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin1 \
filesrc location=/home/chinthaka/Desktop/MageHeenaye101.avi ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! rtpbin1.send_rtp_sink_0 \
rtpbin1.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.100 port=5011 \
rtpbin1.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.100 port=5012 \
udpsrc port=5013 ! rtpbin1.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
\
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin2 \
filesrc location=/home/chinthaka/Desktop/MageHeenaye102.avi ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! rtpbin2.send_rtp_sink_0 \
rtpbin2.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.100 port=5021 \
rtpbin2.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.100 port=5022 \
udpsrc port=5023 ! rtpbin2.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
\
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin3 \
filesrc location=/home/chinthaka/Desktop/MageHeenaye103.avi ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! rtpbin3.send_rtp_sink_0 \
rtpbin3.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.100 port=5031 \
rtpbin3.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.100 port=5032 \
udpsrc port=5033 ! rtpbin3.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
\
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin4 \
filesrc location=/home/chinthaka/Desktop/MageHeenaye104.avi ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! rtpbin4.send_rtp_sink_0 \
rtpbin4.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.100 port=5041 \
rtpbin4.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.100 port=5042 \
udpsrc port=5043 ! rtpbin4.recv_rtcp_sink_0
```

**Receiver:**

```
gst-launch -v \
videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink sync=false async=false \
\
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin1 \
udpsrc port=5011 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z01AFeygbCPNLgIgAAADAC7msoAB4sWywA\\=\\=\\,aOvssg\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)861153369, clock-base=(uint)4026289255, seqnum-base=(uint)30449" ! rtpbin1.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin1. ! rtph264depay ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix. \
udpsrc port=5012 ! rtpbin1.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
rtpbin1.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5013 host=192.168.1.104 \
\
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin2 \
udpsrc port=5021 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z01AFeygbCPNLgIgAAADAC7msoAB4sWywA\\=\\=\\,aOvssg\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)861153369, clock-base=(uint)4026289255, seqnum-base=(uint)30449" ! rtpbin2.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin2. ! rtph264depay ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-120 left=0 ! mix. \
udpsrc port=5022 ! rtpbin2.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
rtpbin2.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5023 host=192.168.1.104 \
\
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin3 \
udpsrc port=5031 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z01AFeygbCPNLgIgAAADAC7msoAB4sWywA\\=\\=\\,aOvssg\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)861153369, clock-base=(uint)4026289255, seqnum-base=(uint)30449" ! rtpbin3.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin3. ! rtph264depay ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-240 left=0 ! mix. \
udpsrc port=5032 ! rtpbin3.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
rtpbin3.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5033 host=192.168.1.104 \
\
gstrtpbin name=rtpbin4 \
udpsrc port=5041 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)\"Z01AFeygbCPNLgIgAAADAC7msoAB4sWywA\\=\\=\\,aOvssg\\=\\=\", payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)861153369, clock-base=(uint)4026289255, seqnum-base=(uint)30449" ! rtpbin4.recv_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin4. ! rtph264depay ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-360 left=0 ! mix. \
udpsrc port=5042 ! rtpbin4.recv_rtcp_sink_0 \
rtpbin4.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5043 host=192.168.1.104
```

I can receive the 4 videos in the same video, but synchronization of each streams is not perfect.

- I just used the same caps for all the receivers. Just found out that caps generated at each time is different at the sender. Is there a good way to send the caps generated to the receiver so that same caps can be used at the receiver?
- Is there any best way to synchronize multiple streams using RTCP?
- Here different ports are used for different RTP and RTCP sessions. Is it advisable or should I use only two ports, one for RTP and one for RTCP.

Please kindly advice. I am quite new to the Gstreamer and trying my best to get familiar with the synchronization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly advise you to start doing this in code instead. launch-lines are great for prototyping, but when it comes to fine-grained control like synchronization, you should be using code instead.

GStreamers rtpbin handles RTCP sync beautifully. If two or more streams have the same cname, it will calculate (using RTCP) the relative timestamp differences between these streams as seen on the sender-side, and then replicate this on the receiver using gstrtpjitterbuffers ts-offset. In theory, if your media was synchronized when it was sent, you should be able to render it synchronized at the receiver as well.